# find Vue routes siblings

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

okay I have this problem. I'm trying to make a generic Vue component which should look at the route, and determine id the route has any siblings, and if it has, the component will make tabs for each sibling including current route.

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried to see if I could use the vue routers matcher to give me multiple matches on a regex, but I had no luck. that way I could take the regex from $router.currentRoute and transform it, to match all siblings, but $router.matcher.match() doesn't seems to respond well to regexes

Comment: maybe store the routes object in a seperated json file, then import it and read it whereve you like?